# How can I clone my Ubuntu drive to another machine?

Tags: clone

I have a project set up on my Ubuntu on Windows 11, and it has a lot of dependencies that took quite a while to set up. I'd like to move to another Windows 11 machine.   Where do I even start? Thanks in advance for the input.

Comment: Is this about WSL? If so that's a Windows question.

Comment: The project is in the ubuntu environment.

Comment: Sure, but how does it answers my question?

Answer (score 0):

If you run Ubuntu under Windows, the most portable way I think is to run Ubuntu as a virtual machine using e.g. [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Then, you can export your Ubuntu in one machine to an image and import it in another; or simply compress the virtual machine folder as a zip file on the first machine, decompress it on the second machine, and double-click the `.vbox` file for your Ubuntu image.